# How many Master Assassins can I train?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

After I train a Master Assassin is it possible to train another to that rank in that den?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not. You can't put 2 master assassins in the same den.

Thing is, I think that , you could train another back up to Master assassin.

So the max number of master assassins at the same time is 7, one for each den.

Comment: This is true even if your master is stationed in another city.